# Please provide explanation and the solution for the below code

Tags: recursion, data-structures, backtracking

What is the return value of f(p, p), if the value of p is initialised to 5 before the call? Note that the first parameter is passed by reference, whereas the second parameter is passed by value.

int f (int &x, int c)

{

```
    c = c — 1;
```

if (c = = 0) return 1;

x = x + 1;

return f(x,c) * x;

```
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this function you are taking (&x, y) x as the reference parameter and c as the value parameter. when you pass the x as a reference it is passed the address of a variable to function so that u directly change the original value from inside your function. But when u passing the value parameter the copy of the variable is passed to the function so you are not able to access the original variable from the inside function.

```
int f(int &x, int c)
{

    c = c - 1;
    if (c == 0)
        return 1;

    x = x + 1;

    return f(x, c) * x;
}
```

```
    int x = 10, c = 10;
    f(x, c); // 565150579
    cout << "Value of x: " << x << endl;
    cout << "Value of c: " << c << endl;
```

Output

```
Value of x: 19
Value of c: 10
```

As u seen the value of c is still 10 but the value of x is changed now.